# Slimbox integration with Virtuemart 2, Joomla 2.5

Tags: virtuemart, slimbox

I am trying to replace the default lightbox 'modal' to 'slimbox', because 'modal' doesn't have the navigation arrows.

[Demo of slimbox with navigations](http://demo.gavick.com/joomla15/may2010/index.php?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=22&category_id=1&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=203)

[Demo of modal without navigations](http://roxzen.com/shop10/index.php/2011-09-01-12-44-00/virtuemart/product-page?virtuemart_product_id=1&virtuemart_category_id=1)

I am using these paths to modify the calling of slimbox

[templatename]/html/com_virtuemart/productdetails/default.php
components/com_virtuemart/productdetails/default.php

Joomla v2.5
Virtuemart 2.0.6
Slimbox2

The following is my attempt:

```
        //Enable Slimbox2 plugin
        $front = JURI::root(true).'/components/com_virtuemart/assets/';
        $document = JFactory::getDocument();
        $document->addStyleSheet($front.'js/slimbox/slimbox.css');
        $document->addScript($front.'js/slimbox/slimbox2.js');      
        $js = 'jQuery(document).ready(function($) { $("a.lightbox").slimbox(); });';
        $document->addScriptDeclaration($js);
        //output thumbnail
        echo $this->product->images[0]->displayMediaThumb('class="product-image"',true,'class="lightbox" rel="lightbox"'.$this->product->virtuemart_product_id.'"',true,true);
        //unset first image not to be show amont additional ones
        unset ($this->product->images[0]);
        ?>
```

But its still not working I wondered what's wrong?

[Reference][3]

Answer (score 0):

You aren't applying the slimbox class to the image reference, your applying it to the container of the image aren't you? You need to deal with the image file url directly in my opinion.

```
// get the file_url of the first image
$imgPath = $this->product->images[0]->file_url;

// output the image
<a class="slimbox" href="<?php echo $imgPath; ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $imgPath; ?>" alt="" />
</a>
```